# cURL in PHP - Handling "Not Secure" Warning on HTTP Site

Tags: php, ssl, web-scraping, curl

I am using a PHP script in my wordpress based [website](https://lescobilling.pk/) that uses cURL to scrape content from a website. The site displays a "Not Secure" warning when accessed manually, but clicking "Send Anyway" allows me to see the desired content.

[check the warning page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Ajj.png)

However, when I use cURL in PHP, I am unable to retrieve the content successfully.

I have tried the following approaches without success:

Ignoring SSL certificate validation using CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.

My code currently looks like this:

```
<?php

require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://www.lesco.gov.pk/Customer_Reg/AccountStatus.aspx';
$nBatchNo=substr($refno,0,2);
$nSubDiv=substr($refno,2,5);
$nRefNo=substr($refno,7,7);
$strRU='U';                        
$postFields = array(
                     'nBatchNo' => $nBatchNo,
                      'nSubDiv' => $nSubDiv,
                      'nRefNo'=> $nRefNo,
                      'strRU'=>$strRU,
                    );
                           
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
url_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

$html = str_get_html($response);
$dom = new \simple_html_dom();
$dom->load($html);
echo $dom;
?>
```

I am not getting any error or exception but the content getting the empty scrapped dom. In my opinion, issue is that the targeted website is at http because almost same kind of script is working fine in my other website which is scrapping a site which is on https.  Is there any configuration required at server side to scrape the http sites.
I appreciate any help or guidance on how to handle this situation with cURL in PHP. Thank you!

Comment: The url provided is HTTP, so certificates shouldn’t matter, although you also have `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, so if a 301 or 302 is encountered, and it is sent to HTTPS, it would be in play. However, when I attempt to resolve the provided domain, it cannot be found. Is there a typo?

Comment: @ChrisHaas No, the provided domain is correct and accessible. strange, it's not accessible to you.  maybe it's restricted in your region.